# Why does the syntax func1(func2)(parameters); work and what is it called?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, higher-order-functions

From the book Eloquent Javascript Third Edition, chapter 5.
I can't seem to find this construct 'f()()' in my research and I would like to learn more about it.

I expected to be able to use

```js
noisy(Math.min(3, 2, 1));
```

but there is no output when doing that.
However, the book example works as intended. But how?

Book example:

```js
function noisy(f) {
  return (...args) => {
    console.log('calling with', args);
    let result = f(...args);
    console.log('called with', args + ', returned', result);
    return result;
  };
}    
noisy(Math.min)(3, 2, 1);
```

Comment: It is returning a function so it can be invoked in the way you show. Allowing to pass one function in, then executing that same function when called

Comment: Better to understand: `const minWithNoise = noisy(Math.min); minWithNoise(3, 2, 1);`. This is called a **higher-order function**, as `noisy` takes a function as an argument and returns another function.

Comment: @mplungjan This has nothing to do with currying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`noisy()` takes a function as an argument (it is evident by the line `let result = f(...args);`). `Math.min(3, 2, 1)` resolves to a value, not a function which it why it doesn't work when passed into `noisy()`.

All that `f()()` means is that the function `f` returns a function, which itself is then executed. It might be easier to understand if we break it down like this:

```js
let g = f();
let result = g();
```

Answer (score 2):

`f()()` invokes a function named `f`, which presumably returns a function - then, the final `()` invokes that returned function. Eg

```js
const f = () => {
  console.log('first invoke');
  return () => console.log('second invoke');
};

const returnedFn = f();
console.log('----');
returnedFn();
```

`f()()` is like the above, except that it doesn't store `returnedFn` in a variable - rather, it just executes the `returnedFn` immediately.

That's the same sort of thing that `noisy` is doing - it returns a function, so if you want to call the returned function immediately without storing the returned function anywhere, put another `()` after calling `noisy`.

The issue with

```
noisy(Math.min(3, 2, 1))
```

is that it's calling `Math.min` immediately - the interpreter simplifies this to

```
noisy(1)
```

before calling `noisy`, so `noisy` doesn't see anything about the `Math.min` or the arguments it was called with. (But the whole point of the `noisy` function is to log both the input and output of a function)

Comment: Is this a form of currying? https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-currying-in-javascript-ceb2188c339

Comment: @mplungjan no. From the article you linked: "*currying transforms a function with multiple arguments into a sequence/series of functions each taking a single argument.*" However, `noisy(Math.min)` still takes multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`noisy` takes a function as an argument and also returns one. Whenever you try `noisy(Math.min(3, 2, 1));` you pass result of `Math.min(3, 2, 1)` to noisy which is the same as calling `noisy(1)`.

You could also split the confusing instruction into two:

```js
let noisyMin = noisy(Math.min);
noisyMin(3, 2, 1);
```

Basically you just get a function as a result of `noisy(Math.min)` and then you call it right away.

`f()()` is only possible if `f()` returns a function.